# Performing Pandas functions on Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, dask

I have a Pandas dataframe that is ~87 million rows. In order to do some processing on it, I made it a Dask dataframe. Problem is that I need to do `unstack` and `plot` which aren't supported by Dask. I have written the Dask dataframe to an h5 file, but get memory issues trying to read it in as a Pandas dataframe. I also get a memory error converting the Dask DF to Pandas.

Essentially what I am trying to do is `df2 = df.groupby(['A','B'])['B'].count().unstack('A')` and then `df2.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True)`.

To get to `df2` I have to left outer join two dataframes. Someone suggested that I use NumPy arrays, but I do not know how I would do the joins and groupby/count/plot. Is this possible with arrays? Would that help with the memory issues? Or is another solution better?

Comment: 1) I'm curious on what kind of processing `pandas/python` cannot do so as you need `Dask`. 2) I found it unreasonable to do a bar plot on that many data. 3) `seaborn` has `barplot` with `hue` option that can help avoid `unstacked`, but won't do `stacked` barplot.

Comment: Generally speaking,pandas supports reading in data in chunks with the parameter `chunksize`. There is also the concept of `lazy loading` involving python generators and also process one at a time. Maybe [this](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/chunking-pandas/) helps also a little?

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @QuangHoang I cannot get to the processed dataframe I need to groupby/plot without Dask since Pandas always gives a memory error. Unfortunately I need to do a stacked bar chart.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your instruction:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['A','B'])['B'].count().unstack('A')
```

Of course, *df* is probably too big to convert it to "pandasonic"
DataFrame, but you can divide the whole operation into steps:

1. *Groupby* and *count* at the *dask* level:

   ```
   wrk = df.groupby(['A','B'])['B'].count().compute()
   ```

   The result should be substantially smaller than your original *df*,
   so you can run also *compute()* to get the "pandasonic" result (probably
   a *Series*), now it should fit in the computer memory.
2. Then *unstack* it (at the *Pandas* level):

   ```
   df2 = wrk.unstack('A')
   ```
3. The last thing is to *plot* it, exactly as you wrote.

Comment: I have tried this, but given the size of the DF it takes way too long.